# Scrapy ignore allowed_domains?

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy

Scrapy ignored my spider rules and follow even not allowed domains.

```
self.start_urls = [ 'http://www.domain.de' ]
self.allowed_domains = [ 'domain.de' ]
```

But sometines it work well and filter not allowed domains, see log:

DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.clubsoundz.fm': http://www.clubsoundz.fm/>

I use the sgmllinkextractor to follow the links, here my "Rule":

rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='get_domain_data', follow=True),
    )

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I think thats exactly the problem i have: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/184
Sounds like there is no real solutions for that issue :(

I think i must filter the urls, before the spider continued the process